# Overlay img with css - visualization issues from different devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to make digital wedding invitations, even though I'm not a web developer.

I'm trying to create a page with a very simple animation where there is an envelope that shows the invitation. I have three simple images overlapped using html and css:

- the front envelope - https://i.ibb.co/HBZsxLt/optipng.png
- the invitation - https://i.ibb.co/h7SfR5L/part.png
- the opend envelope - https://i.ibb.co/HtkgNPy/all.png

I was able to create the code (listed below) for what I want to achieve. 
There are the three images overlapped and I'm able to shift the envelope with two simple lines of JavaScript. The overlapping works perfectly when I open it with Chrome. However, my issues came with the following point:

1. When I open the website with Firefox some pixels of the invitation come out the envelope
2. When I open the website from any smartphone in addition to the envelope-invitation dimension problems all the images are zoomed or moved on the left.

I tried to search if there is any way to overlap the images in an adaptive way (from the device/browser point of view), maybe using only JavaScript but I didn't find anything. I found only the css and html approach the I implemented already below. The simplest thing that I found for solving the issues was to insert a gif in the body but I don't like it very much.

My simple code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <title>Invitation wedding</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: white;
        }

        #container {
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            position: relative;
        }

        img {
            height: 50%; 
            padding: 80px 0;
            overflow: visible;  /* For Firefox */
        }

        .env {
            position: absolute;     
        }

        .partecipazione{
            height: 130%;
            padding-top: 20%;
            position: absolute;
            padding-right: 22px;
        }

        .allEnvelope{
            padding-top: 20%;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="allEnvelope">
            <img id="allEnv" src="all.png"></img> 
        </div> 
        <div class="partecipazione">
            <img id="part" src="part.png"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="env">
            <img id="envelope" src="optipng.png"></img>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var timeline = new TimelineMax();
        timeline.to('#envelope, #allEnv', .6, {y:290}, '+=.7');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I changed some things:

I removed

```
img {
 height: 50%; 
 padding: 80px 0;
 overflow: visible;  /* For Firefox */
}
```

Then added a extra container around all divs inside the envelope for placement:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="envelopeWrapper">
        <div class="allEnvelope">
            <img id="allEnv" src="all.png"></img> 
        </div> 
        <div class="partecipazione">
            <img id="part" src="part.png"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="env">
            <img id="envelope" src="optipng.png"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The styles:

```
.envelopeWrapper{
    width: 603px;
    max-width: 95%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
```

the height here is just to place it in the middle of the screen.
The `max-width` is for mobile devices o if its smaller than the `width` of 603px it will adapt. Also added `position: relative` to adjust the div's within.
Added the styles for all divs/images inside the new wrapper:

```
.env, .partecipazione, .allEnvelope  {
    position: absolute;     
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.envelopeWrapper img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.partecipazione{
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 6%;
    padding-bottom: 7%;
}
```

With position absolute I placed it at the corners of the bottom of the new wrapper-div.
I needed to add padding with percent for .partecipazione because the images wherent properly cut out. It's in percent so it will scale right for mobile devices.

Heres your changed code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <title>Invitation wedding</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: white;
        }

        #container {
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            position: relative;
        }
        .envelopeWrapper{
            width: 603px;
            max-width: 95%;
            height: 500px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .env, .partecipazione, .allEnvelope  {
            position: absolute;     
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
        .envelopeWrapper img{
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .partecipazione{
            padding-left: 2%;
            padding-right: 6%;
            padding-bottom: 7%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="envelopeWrapper">
            <div class="allEnvelope">
                <img id="allEnv" src="all.png"></img> 
            </div> 
            <div class="partecipazione">
                <img id="part" src="part.png"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="env">
                <img id="envelope" src="optipng.png"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var timeline = new TimelineMax();
        timeline.to('#envelope, #allEnv', .6, {y:290}, '+=.7');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I think now you jsut have to adjust the script for the animation a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can add browser prefix with your CSS. Here is new CSS code.

```
<style type="text/css">

 body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: white;
        }

        #container {
            height: 100vh;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            position: relative;
        }

        img {
            height: 50%; 
            padding: 80px 0;
            overflow: visible;  /* For Firefox */
        }

        .env {
            position: absolute;     
        }

        .partecipazione{
            height: 130%;
            padding-top: 20%;
            position: absolute;
            padding-right: 22px;
        }

        .allEnvelope{
            padding-top: 20%;
            position: absolute;
        }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements can overlap for a variety of reasons, by using the property z-index we can make sure that the Letter stays in the vertical order we want it. It is the same as Layers in Photoshop if you have used that.

Using the above example by Puschi, we can add z-index to the following classes:

```
.partecipazione {
   z-index: 1 
}

.env {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

The .env class will stay in the default layer at the bottom, placing the letter above it, then the open envelope above that again. This makes sure that the elements don't overlap.

Here is a Codesandbox using CSS & Javascript

https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-resonance-49b2w?file=/index.html:591-627

By using JavaScript we can fire off the animations after the browser is done loading all the images, making sure that it plays well.

Or we could add interactivity so that when the user clicks or hovers the Envelope it opens.